# Notify if value changes on Intranet webpage

Tags: email, autohotkey, internet-explorer-9, notifications, webpage

On my company Intranet webpage there is a value which is most of time 0 but it can go to 1 or higher.(but only numbers)

Is there a software something  which can notify me automatically if values changes from 0 to something via email or something?

Comment: Just a few questions. Is this the ONLY thing that changes on that page? How often do you want this to be checked? Can you get to that page in the same way from every place you do work (or want to be alerted)? Can you see the value in the page source? –

Comment: It refreshes every 10 mins, and I only care about tht page.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of monitoring software on the market (both free and commercial). They could be configured to load the page and look at values on the page. Probably better to write javascript on the page to do what you want. Without a detailed question it would be hard to say.

Comment: Sorry, quick catch!

Comment: I can't edit that page, just need to monitor it.

Comment: There a lot of options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems